# A derived set of a specific countable union of sets

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

For every $n>1$, let $A_n = \{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{kn(n-1)}\ : k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$. What is
$$\left(\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty} A_n \right)'?$$

My initial thought that it should be $\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\backslash\{1\}\}$, and I can see why irrationals can't be limit points of the set, but what about other rationals? Now I'm not so sure.

Note: $A'$ denotes the set of all limit points of $A$.

Comment: What does $A'$ mean? The set of limit points of $A$?

Comment: @RyanTay Yes, you're correct.

Comment: I don't see why $1$ would be in the derived set

Comment: @Jakobian, ah yes, of course not. I've fixed it.

Comment: You're correct now but I don't see how rationals or irrationals matter here

Comment: Note that $A_n\subseteq [1/n, 1/(n-1)]$. If you pick $x\in (1/n, 1/(n-1))$ then I think its clear $x$ can't be in the derived set of the union? What about other points? Easy case by case analysis